# How to make the concat of list of boolean?

Tags: lua, boolean, concatenation

How I can to concat the boolean values?

I've tried this but get the error that the boolean values are not good for table.concat

```
local tabl = {true, false, true, false, "question", 42}
print (table.concat (tabl, ', '))
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's type coercion works between numbers and strings. That doesn't include `bool` values.

There's at least 2 ways to resolve this:

1. Manually create the output
2. Re-map the table and use `table.concat` again

I'm going to explain the first option here as it won't increase the amount of times you need to loop over the table.

```lua
local tabl = {true, false, true, false, "question", 42}
local output = ""
for i,value in pairs(tabl) do
    output = output .. tostring(value)
    if i ~= #tabl then
        output = output .. ", "
    end
end

print(output) -- true, false, true, false, question, 42
```

If this is something you use often, you could turn it into a function

```lua
function table_safe_concat(tabl, sep)
    local output = ""
    for i,value in pairs(tabl) do
        output = output .. tostring(value)
        if i ~= #tabl then
            output = output .. sep
        end
    end

    return output
end

local tabl = {true, false, true, false, "question", 42}
print(table_safe_concat(tabl, ", "))
```

**For Performance Sake**

I've added this example using a temporary table in the case that string concatenations will cause performance issue.

```lua
function table_safe_concat(tabl, sep)
    local tmp_table = {}
    for i,value in pairs(tabl) do
        table.insert(tmp_table, tostring(value))
    end

    return table.concat(tmp_table, sep)
end

local tabl = {true, false, true, false, "question", 42}
print(table_safe_concat(tabl, ", "))
```

Comment: String concatenations are slow, especially for larger arrays it's faster to create an array first from the results of `tostring`, then use table.concat.

Comment: @Luke100000 sure, for larger strings they definitely can, although it's case-to-case dependant. I've added an example showing this as an alternative

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to go here is to map the table to a table of strings and then call `table.concat`; manually using concatenation results in quadratic performance due to Lua always having to copy the entire immutable string when appending.

I'd first write a map function (that doesn't modify the original table):

```lua
local function map(tbl, func)
    local mapped = {}
    for k, v in pairs(tbl) do mapped[k] = func(v) end
    return mapped
end
```

then simply call `table.concat(map(tabl, tostring), ', ')`.

Bonus: If you're using any Lua standard library extensions (f.E. Penlight, Lume etc.), chances are `map` is already implemented.